Using Python to read character devices, an error occurs when the first read exceeds 4095 bytes
Using Python to read character devices, an error occurs when the first read exceeds 4095 bytes. But when I read 4095 bytes and then read 4096 or more bytes, the error disappears. Also if read block device,does not have this issue.
How can I solve this problem?
Eg:
# ls -l /dev/asmdiske
brw-rw---- 1 grid asmadmin 8, 144 Jun  5 11:29 /dev/asmdiske
"b" This is a block device.

>>> f_read = open('/dev/asmdiske','rb')
>>> f_read.seek(25165824)
>>> context = f_read.read(4096) <-- Block device read without error
>>> f_read.close()

>>> f_read = open('/dev/asmdiske','rb')
>>> f_read.seek(25165824)
>>> context = f_read.read(131072) <--Block device read without error
>>> ff_read.close()


$ls -l /dev/raw/raw1
crw-rw---- 1 grid asmadmin 162, 1 Jun  4 16:45 /dev/raw/raw1
"c" This is a character device.

>>> f_read = open('/dev/raw/raw1','rb')
>>> f_read.seek(25165824)
>>> context = f_read.read(4096) <--read 4096 bytes error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument <-- Error reported here
>>> f_read.close()
>>> 
>>> f_read = open('/dev/raw/raw1','rb')
>>> f_read.seek(25165824)
>>> context = f_read.read(4095) <--read 4095 bytes ok
>>> f_read.close()
>>> 
>>> 
>>> f_read = open('/dev/raw/raw1','rb')
>>> f_read.seek(25165824)
>>> context = f_read.read(4095)
>>> context = f_read.read(4096)  <--Read 4096 bytes immediately after reading 4095 bytes OK
>>> f_read.close()
>>> 
>>> f_read = open('/dev/raw/raw1','rb')
>>> f_read.seek(25165824)
>>> context = f_read.read(4095)
>>> context = f_read.read(8192) <--Read 8192 bytes immediately after reading 4095 bytes OK
>>> f_read.close()
>>> 
>>> f_read = open('/dev/raw/raw1','rb')
>>> f_read.seek(25165824)
>>> context = f_read.read(4095)
>>> context = f_read.read(16384) <--Read 16384 bytes immediately after reading 4095 bytes OK
>>> f_read.close()
>>> 
>>> f_read = open('/dev/raw/raw1','rb')
>>> f_read.seek(25165824)
>>> context = f_read.read(4095)
>>> context = f_read.read(131072) <--Read 131072 bytes immediately after reading 4095 bytes OK
>>> f_read.close()


